# Spawn at random position

Tags: java, android

I have problem with Android. I'm trying make project where I draw circles on a random position. After touch on this circle you will get a score and the circle will disappear. But I have a problem, my object is spawned then disappears without touch and spawns in another location. 
Here is my spawner code.

```
protected void spawner(Canvas canvas,int timer){
    System.out.println(myThread.timer);
if (myThread.timer>100) {
    int x = 200 - generator.nextInt() % (myThread.screenDimX / 2);
    int y = 200 - generator.nextInt() % (myThread.screenDimY / 2);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#800000"));
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y,50, paint);
    myThread.timer=0;
}
}
```

`myThread` is my game loop thread.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only drawing that circle for the instant myThread.timer is greater than 100. What you need to do is add it to an ArrayList, or whatever data structure you want, and then constantly loop over that ArrayList and draw all the circles.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can tell you in general, and I don't know if that's why you have a problem or not, is all UI components manipulation should happen on the UI thread, and not on your other thread. 
It's unclear if you call this method on a callback from the timer thread or on the UI thread. If you're calling it from the UI thread then it might be that both the UI thread and the Timer thread write to myThread.timer, concurrently and  the way it seems, you're not guarding it.

Comment: True, i ll try fix it.

Comment: Also you will have to save your circles positions, and size to do (collision detection) on touch, to figure out which circle you want to remove.(Or more preciously, stop drawing). In this case you will have to clear the canvas by painting a color on top of all your canvas, and then re-draw all the circles that you want to keep.